# Identify distinct codes present in one column but not present in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like the following table. First two columns are list of country codes with pipe separator. There are two group of rows with RANK as 1 and 2.
I am trying to identify the country codes which are present in CountryList1  but not present in the column CountryList1 over a give RANK. For Rank 1 rows, HN JP SK and KY is present in CountryList1 but not present in CountryList2. Likewise, for Rank 2 rows. HN is present in CountryList1 but not present in CountryList2.
I am expecting Output like second table. I do not want to use a function or a procedure but trying to accomplish it using select statement.

Input

```
CountryList1    || CountryList2 || RANK
================||==============||=======
HN|IN|US        || GB|CA|CH|CA  ||  1
JP|CH           || IN|US|LU     ||  1
HN|SK|KY        || GB|CA        ||  1
FI              || IN|MO        ||  1
HN|IN|US        || HN           ||  2
JP|CH           || CH|IN|US     ||  2
HN              || NO           ||  2
```

Output

```
DistinctCountry1    ||  RAN
====================||========  
HN                  ||  1   
JP                  ||  1   
SK                  ||  1   
KY                  ||  1   
JP                  ||  2
```

Comment: Fix your data structure so it is not abominable.  Storing multiple values in a single column is bad form.

Comment: Correct but I can not change the data now.

Comment: Are you using the `array` type? You should normalize the database. SQL becomes convoluted with the data structure you are using.

Comment: Why is JP for rank 1 included in your output?  It exists in both column1 and two for rank 1

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . SQL Server has an array data type?

Comment: Corrected the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My bad, it doesn't have arrays.

Comment: 'FI' should be in your final output as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an abominable data structure.  You should be storing elements of a list as separate values on rows.  But you can do something by splitting the values.  SQL Server 2016 has `string_split()`.  For earlier versions you can find one on the web.

```
with tc as (
      select t.*, s.country1
      from t cross apply
           (string_split(t.countrylist1, '|') s(country1) 
     )
select distinct t.country1, t.rnk
from tc
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where tc.rnk = t2.rnk and
                        tc.country in (select value from string_split(t2.country_list))
                 );
```

This will not be efficient.  And with the data structure you have, there is little scope for improving performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice loop you can use for this:

```
declare @holding table (country1 varchar(max), country2 varchar(max), rank int)
declare @iterator int=1
declare @countrylistoriginal1 varchar(max) 
declare @countrylistoriginal2 varchar(max) 
declare @countrylist1  varchar(max) 
declare @countrylist2  varchar(max) 
declare @rank  int 
while @iterator<=(select max(rowid) from #temp2)
begin
select @countrylistoriginal1=countrylist1+'|',  @rank=[rank] 
from yourtable where rowid=@iterator
while @countrylistoriginal1<>''  
begin
set @countrylist1=left(@countrylistoriginal1,(charindex('|',@countrylistoriginal1)))
set @countrylistoriginal1=replace(@countrylistoriginal1, @countrylist1,'')
select @countrylistoriginal2=countrylist2+'|'  
from yourtable where rowid=@iterator
while @countrylistoriginal2<>''   
begin 
set @countrylist2=left(@countrylistoriginal2,(charindex('|',@countrylistoriginal2)))
set @countrylistoriginal2=replace(@countrylistoriginal2, @countrylist2,'')
insert @holding
select replace(@countrylist1,'|',''), replace(@countrylist2,'|',''), @rank
end
end
set @iterator=@iterator+1
end

select distinct  a.country1,  a.rank from @holding a
left join @holding b on a.country1=b.country2 and a.rank=b.rank where b.country2 is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

**Table Schema and data**

```
CREATE TABLE [tableName](
    [CountryList1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryList2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RANK] [int] NULL
) 

INSERT [tableName] ([CountryList1], [CountryList2], [RANK]) VALUES (N'HN|IN|US', N'GB|CA|CH|CA', 1)
INSERT [tableName] ([CountryList1], [CountryList2], [RANK]) VALUES (N'JP|CH ', N'IN|US|LU', 1)
INSERT [tableName] ([CountryList1], [CountryList2], [RANK]) VALUES (N'HN|SK|KY', N'GB|CA', 1)
INSERT [tableName] ([CountryList1], [CountryList2], [RANK]) VALUES (N'FI', N'IN|MO', 1)
INSERT [tableName] ([CountryList1], [CountryList2], [RANK]) VALUES (N'HN|IN|US', N'HN ', 2)
INSERT [tableName] ([CountryList1], [CountryList2], [RANK]) VALUES (N'JP|CH', N'CH|IN|US', 2)
INSERT [tableName] ([CountryList1], [CountryList2], [RANK]) VALUES (N'HN', N'NO', 2)
```

**SQL Query**

```
;WITH cte AS
(   SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM   (SELECT [value] AS DistinctCountry1, 
                   [rank], 
                   Rtrim(Ltrim([value])) + Cast([rank] AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS colX 
            FROM   tablename 
                   CROSS apply String_split([countrylist1], '|')) tmp 
    WHERE   colx NOT IN (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim([value])) + Cast([rank] AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS colX 
                         FROM   tablename 
                                CROSS apply String_split([countrylist2], '|')) 
) 


SELECT [distinctcountry1], [rank] 
FROM   cte 
ORDER  BY [rank]
```

**Output**

```
+------------------+------+
| distinctcountry1 | rank |
+------------------+------+
| FI               |    1 |
| HN               |    1 |
| JP               |    1 |
| KY               |    1 |
| SK               |    1 |
| JP               |    2 |
+------------------+------+
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19acb/2/0

Note: As others already suggested, you should really consider fixing your table or you'll have to put extra hours when manipulating data.